# Como fazer botão de editar funcionar em um modal window?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, modal

Não estou entendendo como fazer o botão "Editar" funcionar dentro do modal...

Tela (ao clicar em detalhes abre esse modal onde tem o botão editar):
[image]
Meu modal:
[image: Modal]
informações contidas dentro do modal: 
[image]

Comment: Em vez de imagens com código, cole por favor o código pois é mais fácil em caso se a gente querer usar o seu código para ajudar.

Comment: Utilize os comentários em vez de escrever o seu comentário no lugar da resposta. Você é nova por aqui, recomendo que dê uma leitura aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: Obrigada pela dica Luís! Ainda não sei mexer muito bem aqui kk...

Comment: Certo! No caso, eu só faria então uma função JS chamando ela pelo onclik no button Editar... Uma dúvida, no meu modal onde possui as informações php, lá não devo implementar nada ?

Comment: Depende daquilo que voe pretende fazer. Agora você pode criar código na função que vai chamar no onclick, e esse código pode tratar de fazer o que voce quiser. Enviei pedido no linkedin.

Comment: hmmm certo, vou tentar fazer desta forma! Obrigada... 
Vou olhar no linkedin!

Comment: Obrigada Leo...farei a pergunta com relação a isso...

Comment: Pesquisei muito sobre o botão editar em função js, ajax, jquery, php... o que for...vi vários vídeos, não consegui pegar nada de exemplo para fazer  isso...como eu disse, sou iniciante ainda em ti...porém entrei num projeto com a finalidade de aprender, mas estou demorando muito para entender e o prazo está chegando kkk...
Alguém consegue me mostrar um exemplo de código do botão editar que funcionaria para mim ?...Obrigada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tem que criar/chamar alguma acção no botão EDITAR.**

Você pode fazer isso usando JavaScript.

```
<button type="button" onclick="suafuncaoJS()" class="btn btn-dark">Editar</button>
```

Recomendo efecutar uma requisição ajax. Pesquise um pouco sobre isso.

Também pode colocar um href nele e enviar para outra página.

```
<button type="button" href="#paginadedestino" class="btn btn-dark">Editar</button>
```